# Override paintcomponent only works for first the first button of a GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paintcomponent

Hi I just started to program a little game and use java JButtons on it, I created a JButton herited class with overrided paintcomponent, every of these buttons are placed in a JPanel with a grid layout, and the buttons appearances are default ones, exept for the first button(at the top left corner), how to have every button paint as i defined it in my paintcomponent method ?
For the moment i use two classes :

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class World {

private Square[][] map;

public World() {

    // Panels settings

    JPanel mapHUD = new JPanel();
    mapHUD.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    mapHUD.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

    JPanel blueTeamHUD = new JPanel();
    blueTeamHUD.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 400));

    JPanel redTeamHUD = new JPanel();
    redTeamHUD.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 400));

    JPanel spellsHUD = new JPanel();
    spellsHUD.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));

    // Map settings

    map = new Square[8][8];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            map[i][j] = new Square(i, j, i + "" + j);
            mapHUD.add(map[i][j]);
        }

    // Frame settings

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Koko");
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(mapHUD, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(blueTeamHUD, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(redTeamHUD, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(spellsHUD, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}

package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Square extends JButton implements MouseListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int x;
private int y;

public Square(int x, int y, String name) {
    super(name);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fillRect((int) this.getLocation().getX(), (int) this.getLocation().getY(), this.getWidth(),             
this.getHeight());
}

// MouseListener methods

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very wrong:

```
g2.fillRect((int) this.getLocation().getX(), int) this.getLocation().getY(), 
    this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

The location obtained is the location of the component (the button) relative to its container, it's JPanel. You need to draw relative to the component itself starting at 0, 0, and so:

```
g2.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

is what you need

This in fact is why only the first button's drawing works: for the first button, the location *is* at 0, 0 relative to the JPanel.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @PaulDubret: You're very welcome. Note that you will have problems if you give that Square class `public int getX()` and `public int getY()` methods, since JButtons (and all components) already have these methods, and if you accidentally override them, your buttons will be placed in strange locations.

Comment: Following up on @HovercraftFullOfEels' comment, change your x and y class variables to something more meaningful and save yourself some headaches down the road.